# How to use a flag with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I use a flag with numpy? I simplified the function to the bare minimum!

```
import numpy as np
price = np.array([30, 30, 20, 25, 20])
S     = np.repeat(300, len(price))
flag  = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
def Val(S,price,flag = 0):
    p = 4
    if   flag == 0: p = S + price
    elif flag == 1: p = S - price
    return p

Val(S,price,flag.all())
#array([270, 270, 280, 275, 280])

Val(S,price, flag.any())
#array([330, 330, 320, 325, 320])
```

I was expecting this:

```
 Val(S,price,flag.XX)
    #array([330, 330, 280, 325, 320])
```

Here is another function example of equation with a flag. How would I 
apply a numpy solution to it?

From  http://www.espenhaug.com/black_scholes.html

```
   def CND(X):
        (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) = (0.31938153, -0.356563782, 1.781477937, -1.821255978, 1.330274429)
        L = abs(X)
        K = 1.0 / (1.0 + 0.2316419 * L)
        w = 1.0 - 1.0 / sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-L*L/2.) * (a1*K + a2*K*K + a3*pow(K,3) + a4*pow(K,4) + a5*pow(K,5))
        if X<0: w = 1.0-w
        return w
    # Black Scholes Function

    def BlackScholes(CallPutFlag,S,X,T,r,v):
        d1 = (log(S/X)+(r+v*v/2.)*T)/(v*sqrt(T))
        d2 = d1-v*sqrt(T)
        if CallPutFlag=='c': return S*CND(d1)-X*exp(-r*T)*CND(d2)
        else:                return X*exp(-r*T)*CND(-d2)-S*CND(-d1)
```

Comment: Just pass your numpy `flag` array, not the boolean value which is returned by `.all()` or `.any()` methods, and substitute your subroutine body with `return S * flag`. This way you'll obtain your desired result. IDK maybe there is some hidden sense behind your `if` statements which is not obvious for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the

```
if CallPutFlag=='c':
```

`CallPutFlag` is a Python variable  with a character/string value.  So it is used as a switch.  If 'c` use one equation; if not 'c' (probably 'p') use another.

In `Val`, `flag` is used in 2 ways:

```
def Val(S, flag = 0):
    p = 4
    if   flag == 0: p = S * flag
    elif flag == 1: p = S * flag
    return p
```

You test its value, and you multiply with it.  In the `if flag==0` context it has to be a scalar.  Using an array in this context raises a common `ValueError`.

```
In [469]: np.array([0,1,0,1])==0
Out[469]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [470]: if np.array([0,1,0,1])==0:print('yes')
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Python `if` can act or not, it can't flip back and forth for each value of the boolean array.

But for the multiplication `S*flag`, `flag` can be an array that matches `S` in size.

```
In [471]: np.arange(4)*np.array([0,1,0,1])
Out[471]: array([0, 1, 0, 3])
```

So the question is, in `Val` when do you want to return `4`, and when `S*flag`.  As written it is unclear.

===============

```
In [513]: price = np.array([30, 30, 20, 25, 20])
     ...: S     = np.repeat(300, len(price))
     ...: flag  = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
     ...: 
In [514]: np.where(flag, S+price, S-price)
Out[514]: array([330, 330, 280, 325, 320])
```

This list comprehension equivalents are:

```
[s1 if f else s2 for f,s1,s2 in zip(flag,S+price,S-price)]
[s+p if f else s-p for f,s,p in zip(flag,S,price)]
```

A masking approach

```
In [528]: result=S-price
In [529]: result[flag]=S[flag]+price[flag]
In [530]: result
Out[530]: array([330, 330, 280, 275, 280])
```

another masking approach

```
In [543]: p=price.copy()
In [544]: p[flag==0] *= -1
In [545]: p
Out[545]: array([ 30,  30, -20,  25,  20])
In [546]: S+p
Out[546]: array([330, 330, 280, 325, 320])
```

`where` is probably faster, unless calculating the alternatives is expensive.  Or if one of the alternatives generates bad values (e.g. S/0).  But you have to do timings to be sure.

Comment: In which case the `flag` should just be a scalar value - 0, 1 or something else if you want to return `4`.  You can create it from an array with `any or all`, or you can just assign it: `flag=1`.

Comment: Don't pass `Val` an array `flag` parameter - give it a scalar!

Comment: So you want to do the sum for some elements of `S` and the difference for others.  I've added a simple solution using `where`.

Comment: I added some masking alternatives.  Only timings can tell which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

`flag.all()` returns a truthy value when *all* the values of `flag` are truthy (i.e. nonzero), while `flag.any()` does so when `flags` contains *any* number of truthy values. Once some element is proved to be a zero, `False` is returned.

Here you probably want to `zip` the flags and `S` together:

```
for s, flg in zip(S, flag):
    if flg: # do this
    else: # do that
```

All in all, `p` would be defined like this:

```
p = np.array([s * flg for s, flg in zip(S, flg)])
```

This shows an algorithm that could do this, although math can also be helpful:

```
p = flag * S
```

Here `*` represents *Hadamard product* (element-wise product of matrices of *the same size*), as opposed to `np.dot` - matrix multiplication operation.

Comment: @Merlin, NumPy takes care of that. `np.ndarray * np.ndarray => np.ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here and guess that you decided to pass `flag.any()` and `flag.all()` as your parameter because passing `flag` itself raised the following in your `if` statement:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

To fix this issue, remember that `S` and `flag` are numpy arrays of the same size. numpy is really good at doing math element by element on arrays of the same size. Also note that you are doing the exact same thing in both branches of your `if` statement: `p = S * flag`, meaning that you do not really need an `if` statement to decide what to do:

```
def Val(S, flag):
    return S * flag
```

That's all you need here to be able to call `Val(S, flag)` and get the expected array out. This says that each element of the output array is the product of the corresponding elements of `S` and `flag`.

Your current code looks like it is trying to implement an operation that works on a single array element and expecting it to be applied to the entire array. This is not how numpy works in general (although there are ways to write something like that too).